# Is there a way to specify the Media Type while hitting a web-service using a URL from browser[Purely for testing purpose]

Tags: java, rest

I want to test my REST Web-Service.
Is there a way to specify the Media Type while hitting a the URL from browser. I understand that I can do this by using a HttpClient where i can explicitly specify the MIME type, but I want to test it using my browser.
Say I have I have three methods that produce XML/JSON/HTML :

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
          return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
         return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }
```

Can i tell my browser explicitly to hit a particular one ?

Comment: if your "browser" is curl or wget, that's easily done … for Firefox or Chrome, you'll probably need an extension …

Comment: Yes i am working with Chrome ,and by extension , you mean they have specific plugins to do this thing ? I will check.

Comment: and i cant use curl/wget , this testing is to be done by Client's who don't know things beyond the boundary of hitting a given URL from a browser(thankfully its not Internet explorer) ...

Comment: Chrome extensions such as `REST console` will do it. If you want to give simple access to non-techie users, you should think about providing them a web UI over your REST services.

Comment: REST console worked for me...although had to do a little explaining to the client , better than spending time on making my own UI for them :) !!

Comment: try postman - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html
>
> If a resource class is capable of producing more that one MIME media
>   type then the resource method chosen will correspond to the most
>   acceptable media type as declared by the client. More specifically the
>   Accept header of the HTTP request declares what is most acceptable.

So your question is really "How can I control the "Accept" HTTP header in my GET request?"

The answer is to use a tool like curl, wGet, or a browser extension like postman (Chrome) or [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) (FireFox).

ALSO:
Here are some links on using the Chrome REST Console:

- https://splash.riverbed.com/docs/DOC-1601
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbilAAOVcnI

Answer (score 0):

Browser extension should do the work. my favorite chrome extension is [postman](http://www.getpostman.com/)

But, like Stephane mentined, please consider building nice testing arena for your api. Best fee tool for that job is Swagger by Wordnik. Check it out http://swagger.wordnik.com/

Comment: Is there any such plugin available for IE as well ...?

Comment: @PrakharDixit
not sure about IE, haven't used it for a while. 
However, there is nice firefox tool for same use case: http://www.restclient.net/